# Use windows environment variables in docker-compose.yaml file

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-for-windows, docker-compose

I would like my Windows Username available in my (Linux) container as `$WINDOWS_USERNAME` using docker-compose. But when I try accessing it with `${env:USERNAME}`, I get this error:

```sh
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "docker_in_docker": "WINDOWS_USERNAME=${env:USERNAME}"
```

If I try `WINDOWS_USERNAME=$env:USERNAME` it tells me that `env` is not set, and sets my variable to `:USERNAME`.

Is there an official way to use window environment variable with docker-compose?

Here is a sample from my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  docker_in_docker:
    container_name: docker_in_docker
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /c:/c
    environment:
      - WINDOWS_USERNAME=${env:USERNAME}
```

Comment: Try `${USERNAME}`.

Comment: @harrymc Nope :(  (I also tried `${USERNAME}`, `%USERNAME%`, and `%env:USERNAME%`.)